# How to find the names of partitions of a given block device?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, partition, block-device

Given a block device (e.g, `/dev/sda`), how to determine the names of its partitions (if any) in a script (i.e. without user interaction)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lsblk` prints out all related block devices. This includes the partitions of said device. Since it of course includes the device itself and `lsblk` does not allow for excluding specific devices the example solution below simply uses inverted `grep`:

```
lsblk -o KNAME -n /dev/mmcblk0 | grep -v "^mmcblk0$"
```

For full paths (which also simplifies the generation of the grep string) one can use `-p`, e.g.:

```
lsblk -po KNAME -n /dev/mmcblk0 | grep -v "^/dev/mmcblk0$"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of tools which you can use for this. One of the tools which I tend to use a lot is `fdisk`. fdisk is something which will list the partitions of your block device and also state the exact sizes for you. `fdisk` is quite a versatile program which can also modify the internal properties of your partitions in terms of storage so be very careful using it.

In the case of listing a partition you simply want to execute the following command:
`fdisk -l <name of block device>`. From this point you're then able to see the exact sizes, name and type of the partitions you seek. If you would like to use `fdisk` further for other uses relating to the hard disk then use the `man` command to open the manual page for `fdisk`:

`man fdisk`

Comment: I phrased my question not carefully enough and have edited it now. I meant automatically within a script and without any user interaction. There are lots of way for finding this out interactively in Linux.

Comment: In this case you should consult the bash programming language. You will be able to use Linux commands in a programmable environment and you won't require any further user interaction. I understand what you're asking now. Please feel free to write your script and message me if you would like a hand or just general feedback